# Automatically remove commercials from internet radio recordings

Tags: internet-radio

For Video they have [Comskip](http://www.kaashoek.com/comskip/) and [Cbreak](http://devices.natetrue.com/cbreak/). Any audio equivalent ?

Comment: are you wanting just the music played ? if so there's possibly some options. Something like streamripper will rip each song into a separate music file. Then you could maybe remove any file smaller than a given size, on the basis that most adverts last a lot less time than a song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not really, the reason being is there are things you can detect in the video stream (for example the station's logo in the bottom right corner, or the rating of the show in the top left) that only show up while the show is running. There is nothing like that for a program listening to the audio to pick up on.

---

Using [Sirex's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/388389/automatically-remove-commercials-from-internet-radio-recordings#comment438283_388389) you could do this yourself with not too much trouble. You will just use [StreamRipper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/index.php) to separate out to segments, then you feed those segments in to [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me/start#identify) to find out what are songs and what is not (this may take a little scripting with your language of choice), the "songs" you can't ID you can remove from the list to be checked by hand and the songs it can ID you just tag and move to your collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Streamripper only supports mp3/aac/ogg but I get the point. This assumes of course the station broadcasts metadata for the recorder to know where to split the files, in which case you could probably go by the metadata without Echoprint.

Comment: Not all radio stations play music. What about talk radio stations? Can StreamRipper still separate the talk from the commercials that are significantly louder?